# How to search multiple sites at once?

Tags: search

Is there any way to send a search query to several websites at once and browse results?

For example, I want to buy edible paper. Paper on which you can write and take a bite off for a nutritious snack. I've found about 15 websites that sell this type of paper and have a search field.

Is there any way to search all of those 15 websites at once with one single search query and view results individually later instead of going to each website manually, entering the search term 15 times?